# Retrofit Gson deserialize string special characters

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I have that json

```
[
  {
    TITLE: "Yoy’s Child"
  },
    TITLE: "Look at me – Stop looking"
  }
]
```

I use retrofit and gson and the results are

```
Yoy&#8217;s Child
Look at me &#8211; Stop looking
```

The problem is encoding that special characters. Here's my code

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
                }
            });

    gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(WEB_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();

    apiService = restAdapter.create(APIService.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the disableHtmlEscaping command to the GsonBuilder constructor.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping();
```

Comment: Still the same output

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I debugged the application and found out that the return json had the symbol issues. All I had to do was just to encode json to UTF-8.